# How to delete synonyms?

Tags: python

I'm creating a code on Python 3.4.3. I have a linguistic program. This part of my code has to delete the next word if it is a synonym of a previous word. Firstly, we have to create a list of synonyms for each word. Then we transform all our lists into sets. But eventually, we have to compare our lists to check if they have the same synonyms. I don't know how to compare them. We have to keep just 1 word if there is a synonym of it next.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
text = ['','','']
text4 = []

def f4(text):
    global text4

    synonyms = []
    for sentence in text:
        d = ' '
        sentence = sentence.split(d)
        for word in sentence:
            syn = []
            for syn in wordnet.synsets(word):
                for lemma in syn.lemmas():
                    syn.append(lemma.name())
            synonyms.append(syn)

    synonyms2 = []
    for x in synonyms:
        x = set(x)
        synonyms2.append(x)
```

Comment: This question could be much more useful for others if only you could find the general case involved. Try to identify the single (syntax-related?) problem you are facing and edit your question accordingly!

Comment: I'd suggest starting with pseudocode first.

Comment: Which part of the code is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

**My code has to delete the next word if it is a synonym of a previous word.**

I would suggest a different algorithm. Here's an example:

```
text = 'run race stroll rush nice lovely mean kind' # example text
synonyms = [] # contains a list of synonym lists
synonyms.append( ['run', 'race', 'rush'] ) # run synonyms
synonyms.append( ['nice', 'lovely', 'kind'] ) # nice synonyms

def in_synonyms(list_of_synonym_lists, word):
    """ Returns index of synonym list the word is in; -1 if isn't found. """
    for index, synonym_list in enumerate(list_of_synonym_lists):
        if word in synonym_list:
            return index
    return -1

# The algorithm
split_text = text.split()
index = 1
while index < len(split_text):
    if in_synonyms(synonyms, split_text[index]) != -1: # if word is in any synonyms list
        if in_synonyms(synonyms, split_text[index]) == in_synonyms(synonyms, split_text[index-1]):
            # if word before is in the same synonyms list as current we delete the current
            # one and start over again
            del(split_text[index])
            index = 1 # restart the algorithm
        else:
            index += 1 # continue on forward
text = ' '.join(split_text)
```

This code:

- Creates a list of synonyms lists
- Iterates through the words of text

  - If previous word is in the same list of synonyms as the current one, we delete the current one and restart the algorithm
  - Else we continue on forward

I haven't tested it yet but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter words out which are repeats, tautologies, synonyms of preceding words:

```
filtered = []
previous_word = None
for word in sentence.split(' '):
    if previous_word and synonymous(word, previous_word):
        continue
    else:
        filtered.append(word)
        previous_word = word

' '.join(filtered)
```

You could do this in a list comprehension:

```
words = sentence.split(' ')
new_sentence = ' '.join(word for word, previous in zip(words, [None] + words)
                        if not synonymous(word, previous))
```